# specifying redirect url onlogin in <div class="fb-login-button">

Tags: facebook, fbconnect

This is how i normally specify a redirect url in fbml f-connect tag

`<fb:login-button onlogin='redirect-url'>f-connect</fb:login-button>`

How do i specify a redirect url 'on login' in:

`<div class="fb-login-button">f-connect</div>` ??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just do it the other way now. Since there is no any `redirect_uri` for Login Button you need to `FB.Event.subscribe` for `auth.authResponseChange` event to know then user is logged-in:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    window.top.location = '//redirect-url.com';
  }
});
```